# How to pass the value to the bootbox in the loop

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I have a problem. How to pass the value of the variable to the bootbox in the loop.
I have an array taken from the database and displayed in a loop:

```
<tr>
    <td>Order nr1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <button id="confirm-delete-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Order nr2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <button id="confirm-delete-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And Js Bootbox:

```
$('#confirm-delete-modal').click(function() {
    var tesst = "aaa";
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Delete?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'YES',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'NO',
                className: 'btn-success'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result)
            {
                window.location.href = "/"+ tesst
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to pass a separate Id to the link for each row in the loop.How can I do this?

Comment: Your first problem is that you allow a duplicate `id` to be used, an `id` must be unique in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `data-index=""` to the HTML, this way you can send "parameters" to your click function.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    alert(index);
});
```

```html
<button id="confirm-delete-modal" type="button"
   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-index="1">Delete</button>
<button id="confirm-delete-modal" type="button"
   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-index="2">Delete</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that I also changed your selector, since it was selecting just one HTML element id (you have two elements with the same id). Try to create a new class and selecting this class instead (in this example I used just the normal `btn` class).